# Stop globals.d.ts triggering Visual Studio TypeScript services

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code, tsc

I'm working on a legacy code base with Visual Studio 2015. There is a lot of Javascript code, and again for legacy reasons I can't just add Typescript.

Any new Javascript that is written is done in VS Code and in order to improve the quality of the Javascript I've been using the TS language services native to VS Code. This involves the use of `// @ts-check` and `globals.d.ts` so that I can remove warnings about jQuery's `$` not being found, among other things.

This works fine but now every time Visual Studio 2015 finds the new `globals.d.ts` file it's triggering a bunch of Typescript features and adding Typescript related properties to the actual .csproj

This is not a desirable feature in this case; the code is legacy and using a legacy build system, adding new language features in the csproj is a big no-no unfortunately.

Is there a way I can have the file existing while also not causing Visual Studio 2015 to try use it? The file exists solely for VS Code's sake.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to play around with a `tsconfig.json` file to stop the TypeScript tab being active in Visual Studio, although it will still be looking at the TypeScript in this case.

If you want to get serious with disabling the compiler in your project, there is a [documented feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html#typescriptcompileblocked) to block the TypeScript compiler.

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

This would require a small change to the project file, as this needs to be placed in there, inside a `<PropertyGroup>`.